# How to include many julius files in a single page

Tags: javascript, haskell, yesod

I currently have a route in my app which look like :

```
getBookmarksR :: Handler Html
getBookmarksR = do
    defaultLayout $ do
      setTitle "Bookmarks"
      addScript $ StaticR js_jquery_1_10_2_js
      addScript $ StaticR js_handlebars_1_1_2_js
      addScript $ StaticR js_ember_1_2_0_js
      addScript $ StaticR js_ember_data_js
      $(widgetFile "bookmarks")
```

It include ember and its dependencies.

So now I want to develop the rest of the javascript using Yesod's Julius.
But for now the only file I can work with is templates/bookmarks.julius because it is loaded automatically by $(widgetFile "bookmarks")

So how can I integrate many julius file in a way to split my code between many files ?

Comment: Why don't you want to put other Julius files on the local server and use addScript for those also, just like you did for jquery, etc, above?

Comment: Because I do want to use the features of julius over basic javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
toWidget $(juliusFile "templates/foo.julius")
```

But often times, I'll just use `$(widgetFile "foo")`. If there are no `foo.hamlet`, `foo.lucius`, or `foo.cassius` files, it works out to the same thing.